# 3 monitors 1 PC

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have being using 2 monitors plugged on motherboard (1 HDMI, 1 VGA)

Now i found a VGA graphic card (old one) and im trying to setup 3 monitors, but my PC only works on the onboard graphic or the grafic card at a time, im trying to make work of the 3 monitors together

iGPU Multi-Monitor setting is Enable

Try alternate PCIE>iGPU and iGPU>PCIE already

MotherBoard - ASUS P8H77-M

Processor - Intel i3

4Gb DDR3 RAM

Grafic card - PCIE dont know the model nvidia (G86)

Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the right BIOS setting to me - I have a similar setup (8800 GT (G92) with two screens and an ASUS B85M-G with a single screen) where this works. Only after my OS loads will all three monitors show something though.

Things to check would be:

- Up-to-date drivers for both integrated and discrete GPUs for Windows
  10
- ensure all monitors are set to appropriate resolutions in Windows
- try one monitor connected to each, in case there is some hardware limitation
- BIOS update (use caution, skip if uncomfortable with trying this)

Comment: Tnx
I didnt update the driver cause windows did not recognize the card
I clean up the card and the whole pc, and i could identify the card
After updating the driver it work